# Why am i getting this error? LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

The elastic search instance is working perfectly. but when i try to ingest data using logstash i receive that the host in unreachable. i have been able to import some data with file beats but logstash doesnt seem to work. i've tried to import both from my host machine and from a logstash docker container on the same server.

```
   sh-4.2$ logstash -f ./logstash-companies.config --path.data /usr/share/logstash/data1
Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-05-20T10:59:57,098][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties
[2021-05-20T10:59:57,109][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.12.1", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.10+9 on 11.0.10+9 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[2021-05-20T10:59:57,535][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2021-05-20T10:59:58,111][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] Internal collectors option for Logstash monitoring is deprecated and targeted for removal in the next major version.
Please configure Metricbeat to monitor Logstash. Documentation can be found at:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html
[2021-05-20T10:59:58,605][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[2021-05-20T10:59:59,123][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2021-05-20T10:59:59,536][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
[2021-05-20T10:59:59,718][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'"}
[2021-05-20T10:59:59,754][ERROR][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Failed to fetch X-Pack information from Elasticsearch. This is likely due to failure to reach a live Elasticsearch cluster.
[2021-05-20T11:00:00,131][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9601}
[2021-05-20T11:00:02,121][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 48 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 23 keys and 47 values
[2021-05-20T11:00:02,548][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[2021-05-20T11:00:02,677][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@127.0.0.1:9200/]}}
[2021-05-20T11:00:02,731][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@127.0.0.1:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@127.0.0.1:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
[2021-05-20T11:00:02,743][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]}
[2021-05-20T11:00:02,832][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>24, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>3000, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-companies.config"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x6dc05243 run>"}
[2021-05-20T11:00:04,132][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.3}
[2021-05-20T11:00:04,411][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2021-05-20T11:00:04,471][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][9cb3bb91aca8b7a5d2500988664aee2ec84b8cd9c7900317fa5ddd503b391d52] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2021-05-20T11:00:04,473][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2021-05-20T11:00:07,759][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@127.0.0.1:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@127.0.0.1:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
```

My ingest config is as follows :

```
input {
        file {
        path => "/opt/logstash/bin/BasicCompanyDataAsOneFile-2021-05-01.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}

filter {
  csv {
          separator => ","
          columns => ["CompanyName", "CompanyNumber", "RegAddress.CareOf", "RegAddress.POBox", "RegAddress.AddressLine1", " RegAddress.AddressLine2", "RegAddress.PostTown", "RegAddress.County", "RegAddress.Country", "RegAddress.PostCode", "CompanyCategory", "CompanyStatus", "CountryOfOrigin", "DissolutionDate", "IncorporationDate", "Accounts.AccountRefDay", "Accounts.AccountRefMonth", "Accounts.NextDueDate", "Accounts.LastMadeUpDate", "Accounts.AccountCategory", "Returns.NextDueDate", "Returns.LastMadeUpDate", "Mortgages.NumMortCharges", "Mortgages.NumMortOutstanding", "Mortgages.NumMortPartSatisfied", "Mortgages.NumMortSatisfied", "SICCode.SicText_1", "SICCode.SicText_2", "SICCode.SicText_3", "SICCode.SicText_4", "LimitedPartnerships.NumGenPartners", "LimitedPartnerships.NumLimPartners", "URI", "PreviousName_1.CONDATE", " PreviousName_1.CompanyName", " PreviousName_2.CONDATE", " PreviousName_2.CompanyName", "PreviousName_3.CONDATE", " PreviousName_3.CompanyName", "PreviousName_4.CONDATE", " PreviousName_4.CompanyName", "PreviousName_5.CONDATE", " PreviousName_5.CompanyName", "PreviousName_6.CONDATE", " PreviousName_6.CompanyName", "PreviousName_7.CONDATE", " PreviousName_7.CompanyName", "PreviousName_8.CONDATE", " PreviousName_8.CompanyName", "PreviousName_9.CONDATE", " PreviousName_9.CompanyName", "PreviousName_10.CONDATE", " PreviousName_10.CompanyName", "ConfStmtNextDueDate", "ConfStmtLastMadeUpDate"]
        }
}


output {
        elasticsearch { hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
                index => companies
                user => ["elastic"]
                password => ["mypassword"]
        }


}
```

Comment: Is elasticsearch running in the same host/container as logstash?

Comment: Can you paste the working Filebeat config too?